# Setting ByteBuf ENDIANNESS in Netty4

Tags: netty

In Netty 3 we enforced LITTLE_ENDIAN ChannelBuffers on each end using

```
bootstrap.setOption("child.bufferFactory", new HeapChannelBufferFactory(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN));
```

but in Netty 4, configuration of ByteBuf now appears to be via ChannelOption.ALLOCATOR:

```
    bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.ALLOCATOR, someAllocator);
```

All we really want to do is decorate UnpooledByteBufAllocator, but it is final and the methods
we need to decorate are protected, so we cant extend the class or delegate to it. We have
had to resort to a proxy approach:

```
private static class AllocatorProxyHandler implements InvocationHandler {
    private final ByteBufAllocator allocator;

    public AllocatorProxyHandler(ByteBufAllocator allocator) {
        this.allocator = allocator;
    }

    public static ByteBufAllocator proxy(ByteBufAllocator allocator) {
        return (ByteBufAllocator) Proxy.newProxyInstance(AllocatorProxyHandler.class.getClassLoader(), new Class[]{ByteBufAllocator.class}, new AllocatorProxyHandler(allocator));
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        Object result = method.invoke(allocator, args);
        if (result instanceof ByteBuf) {
            return ((ByteBuf) result).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
        } else {
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

setting the Bootstrap option like this:

```
    bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.ALLOCATOR, AllocatorProxyHandler.proxy(UnpooledByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT));
```

Is there some other (better) way to do this we are missing?

Answer (score 2):

Netty 4.0's `ByteBuf` is big-endian by default.  You can get the little-endian view of the `ByteBuf` using the `order(ByteOrder)` method:

```
ByteBuf buf = ctx.alloc().buffer();
ByteBuf leBuf = buf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
leBuf.getByte(...);
...
```

This is by design to avoid any confusion caused by keeping byte order as a state variable.  If there is a good reason why it has to provide a way to change the default byte order, please let us know so we can reconsider this decision.

Comment: Perhaps accessor functions such as getIntLE or getIntBE could be useful?

Comment: @Climax Yes, that's the plan actually.

Comment: LE or BE does not make difference when reading single byte.. Would be better to use different type (e.g. short) in LE example.

Comment: Also order() method is deprecated in most recent versions. Methods with 'LE' suffix should be called explicitly, e.g. `writeShortLE()`, `readIntLE()` and so on.